# Non-correlated significant variables making model performance worse

Tags: r, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model

I am making  Poisson and tweedie GLM models to segment risk. I have one extremely highly significant variable that segments risk very well ($p < 1e-16$ from the model output). However, I also have a few other variables that are not correlated (correlation coefficient $< 0.1$) with the extremely significant one (with $p \approx 1e-6$ from the model output) but these reduce the performance of the model. This results seems very unusual. The model performance metric is a double lift chart (example of one can be found on page 71/72 on http://www.casact.org/pubs/monographs/papers/05-Goldburd-Khare-Tevet.pdf). It would be great if I could get any kind of explanation why this is the case.

Comment: Could you add the following to make more insightful what your situation is: (1) what do you mean by correlations between the variables (have you made correlation matrices and tested these for significant correlations, hence the p-value; if so I'd be more interested in the correlation coefficient)? (2) What kind of GLM have you made (linear, logistic, poisson, etc.)? (3) What kind of model performance statistic are you referring to?

Comment: @IWS I have updated my question.